# The error occurred after the last update

Tags: errors, hyperref, bugs, update

After latest  update of TeXLive2019 I get an error with my code, thet previously worked fine. I associate this error with the latest update, possible some conflict of `hyperref` and `answers` packages, or something else.

> \openout4 = `MWE-Answers.tex'.
>
> ! Bad space factor (0).  @savsf 
>                            l.30 ...rotect\section*{\nameref*{\currfilebase}}}
>                                                      I allow only values in the range 1..32767 here.

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{currfile}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{problemstyle}%
{\hypertarget{problem:##2}{}\item[\theorem@headerfont{\hyperlink{solution:##2}{##2.}}] }
{\hypertarget{problem:##2}{}\item[\theorem@headerfont{\hyperlink{solution:##2}{##2.}}] (##3)}

\makeatother

\theoremstyle{problemstyle}
\newtheorem{problem}{}
%\renewcommand{\theproblem}{\thechapter.\arabic{problem}}
\Newassociation{solution}{Solution}{answer}
\renewenvironment{Solution}[1]{%
    \par%
    \hypertarget{solution:#1}{\noindent\hyperlink{problem:#1}{\bfseries #1.}}
}{%
    \par%
}

\begin{document}
%=========================================================
\chapter{Some Title}\label{\currfilebase}
\Opensolutionfile{answer}[\currfilebase-Answers]
\Writetofile{answer}{\protect\section*{\nameref*{\currfilebase}}}
%=========================================================
\Opensolutionfile{answer}[Answers]

\begin{problem}
Problem with solution
\begin{solution}
Solution
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Problem with NO solution
\end{problem}

\Closesolutionfile{answer}
\newpage
\input{\jobname-Answers}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put

```
\makeatletter
\def\nobreak{\penalty\@M}
\makeatother
```

at the start of the file you will restore the behaviour, I've not traced enough to say yet where the correct fix should be.

Comment: A better fix is to have `\chapter` *after* `\Opensolutionsfile` and `\Writetofile`.

Comment: @egreg that is a better fix, but isn't "restoring the old behaviour" (although that might be the correct thing to do for he new behaviour... not sure yet:-)